# Рандомный выбор карт из колоды

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как организовать рандомный выбор карт из колоды?
Есть колода из 52 карт, уже перетасованная.
Как генератором случайных чисел выбирать карту из массива?
Т.е. нужно учитывать количество оставшихся элементов чтобы не выйти за границу диапазона и каждый раз при выборе убирать эту карту из массива.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940180/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82

Comment: Если колода перетасованная, то зачем еще генератор случайных чисел? Берите всегда первую (или последнюю), и удаляйте.

Comment: Черт, правильно же..  А в цикле по массиву можно менять количество элементов этого массива? Просто там где я раньше прогал - была такая оказия "СписокЗначений". При удалении элементов из списка он автоматически как говорится "смыкал ряды".

Comment: Возьмите `std::vector` и не напрягайтесь.

Comment: А удаления, как такового из массива в C++ нет? Как я понял - нужно создать массив-копию исходного, и перенести туда только нужные элементы?